# Does EC2 instance by default include EBS Volume or Instance Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After Selecting AMI I launch a new EC2 instance, it automatically creates 8 GB Volume associated with the instance containing the selected AMI. Is this Volume instance store or EBS Volume? Is this Volume called Root Volume?

When I create a new instance, it does not give the option of specifying size of this Volume containing AMI.

Added:
Its t2.nano and ubuntu AMI.

I was reading AWS book and it mentions instance store volume which is physical local storage in the actual server hosting EC2 instance but this instance store is destroyed when EC2 is stopped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this Volume instance store or EBS Volume? Is this Volume called Root Volume?

If you talk about T2.micro instance then it will be **EBS volume** and its for **root**.

You can set the **size of the volume on creation** of an instance or **resize it later** at any time. However, when you do resize the volume later you will have to manually resize the root partition on the instance. For example, for linux the instructions are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).

### During creation of an instance

[image]

### Resize later in EC2's `Volumes` tab

[image]

Comment: its t2.nano but soon will graduate to micro. Its Ubuntu AMI. thank u

Comment: @ace No problem. Glad it worked out. p.s. It will be same for t2.nano.

Answer (score 4):

This will probably create a [GP2 volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html#EBSVolumeTypes_gp2) for you, however for some legacy instances you might see this as an instance backed volume.

**Although** it can also depend on the AMI the instance is booted from, some legacy AMIs may have been created to use an instance store backed instance.

Yes this **is the root volume**.

During creation it **should allow** you change the 8GB to a larger size, however you can also [modify the volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html) later to increase its size or modify its type.

For some instance types you might find both a root volume and a local nvme storage volume.

Amazon provide a page on the [root volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html) that should help you understand this concept